# Average of character fields?

Tags: sql, average, percentage

I am needing to average a column that is characters and not integers.  For example clients order two ways from my company...phone and internet.  I am being asked to get a percentage of how they all order.

```
Cust |  OrderType
-----------------
A    |  Phone
A    |  Phone
A    |  Phone
A    |  Internet
B    |  Internet
B    |  Internet
B    |  Phone
```

How can I pull this data and show my managers that Customer A orders by phone 80% of the time and Internet 20% of the time and Customer B orders by phone 66% of the time and Internet 33% of the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Cust,
SUM(CASE WHEN OrderType = 'Phone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(*)  'Phone percentage',
SUM(CASE WHEN OrderType = 'Phone' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) * 100 / COUNT(*) 'Internet percentage'
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Cust
```

Comment: Sorry, it was an  error in my answer. I have updated it. Also you can check my query here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/551d8/9

Comment: This worked...kind of.  After each line it gives me a total of 100% instead of giving me a percentage of all of the lines for a customer put together.

Comment: Sorry can not understand you. Can you update your question with example how it works?

Comment: Cust |  Column_1 | Phone | Internet<br/>
A       Phone       100      0<br/>
A       Phone       100      0<br/>
B       Phone       0       100<br/>
B       Phone       100       0<br/>

These aren't the actual results but this is what I am getting

Comment: Ahhhhh...nevermind. I figured it out.  My issue is that I was also pulling an order number.  Took that out and the percentages are correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You basically want the total number of orders divided by the count of each type of order.

```
/*
create table #tmp (Cust CHAR(1), OrderType VARCHAR(10))

INSERT #tmp VALUES ('A', 'Phone')
INSERT #tmp VALUES ('A', 'Phone')
INSERT #tmp VALUES ('A', 'Phone')
INSERT #tmp VALUES ('A', 'Internet')
INSERT #tmp VALUES ('B', 'Internet')
INSERT #tmp VALUES ('B', 'Internet')
INSERT #tmp VALUES ('B', 'Phone')
*/

SELECT
     Cust, 
     OrderType, 
     (1.0 * COUNT(*)) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp t2 WHERE t2.Cust = t.Cust) pct,
     cast(cast(((1.0 * COUNT(*)) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp t2 WHERE t2.Cust = t.Cust) ) * 100 as int) as varchar) + '%' /* Formatted as a percent */
FROM #tmp t
GROUP BY Cust, OrderType
```

Comment: This would be great except that I can't create temp tables in the database.  I guess I could but my manager would not like it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This sql below

Data Example (this data is kept in a temporary table @temp)

```
Cust  OrderType
----- --------------------------------------------------
A     Phone
A     Phone
A     Phone
A     internet
B     internet
B     internet
B     internet
B     Phone
```

SQl:

```
select Cust, OrderType, count(orderType)as float)*100/cast((select count(cust) 
from @temp where cust= a.cust) as Percentage from @temp a
group by cust,OrderType
```

Result:

```
Cust  OrderType                                          Percentage
----- -------------------------------------------------- ----------------------
A     internet                                           25
A     Phone                                              75
B     internet                                           75
B     Phone                                              25
```

Note: To Create @temp

```
Declare @temp table
(
 Cust nvarchar(5),
 OrderType nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @temp values
('A','Phone'),
('A','Phone'),
('A','Phone'),
('A','internet'),
('B','internet'),
('B','internet'),
('B','internet'),
('B','Phone')
```